# Regex replace to ignore certain pattern at the beginning if exists and format the rest

Tags: oracle-12c, regex

How to use regex replace to ignore country code if it exists, I tried to use

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number,'^/(?:011.44.)([[:digit:]]{3})\.([[:digit:]]{3})\.([[:digit:]]{4})$',
'\1-\2-\3') regex_output
from employees;
```

but it doesn't work,
the next one works for the format `515.123.4567`

```
'([[:digit:]]{3})\.([[:digit:]]{3})\.([[:digit:]]{4})$'
```

but they have some phone numbers like `011.44.1345.729268` and I want to ignore 011.44 if exists at the beginning of numbers using one regex syntax if possible.

This is supposed to be the ignore syntax but its not working `^/(?:011.44.)` or `^/(?!011.44.)` I also tried `^/(?!([[:digit:]]{3})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.)` again doesn't work
Note I can do it using other functions, this question related to regex only
and I am using oracle HR database

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  original numbers     |      expected output   |
--------------------------------------------------
|       phone_number    |     regex_output       |
--------------------------------------------------
|   515.123.4567        |   515-123-4567         | 
|   515.123.4567        |   515-123-4567         | 
|   515.123.4567        |   515-123-4567         | 
|   515.123.4567        |   515-123-4567         | 
|   011.44.1345.729268  |   134-572-9268         | 
|   011.44.1345.729268  |   134-572-9268         |
|   011.44.1345.729268  |   134-572-9268         |
|   011.44.1345.729268  |   134-572-9268         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

[Fiddle sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7ce1b45abec750112d583b3bcb846b9)

---

**Update:**

If anyone else is wondering I found out that in oracle [non capturing groups are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195017/oracle-regexp-limitation/68195063#68195063)

> (?:...), non-capturing groups, are not supported, you should replace
> them with capturing groups. (Note that (:? is not a non-capturing
> group, it is just an optional colon at the start of the second
> capturing group in the pattern).
> -- Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that at the moment it's not upvoteable! You should provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with a few sample data points and your desired result! At the moment, it's very difficult to get a feeling for exactly what you want. I have no visual image of your input string(s) (please provide ~ 5) and your desired result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you normalize your strings before applying the regular expression:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  REPLACE(phone_number, '.'),
  '^(01144)?([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{4})$',
  '\2-\3-\4'
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40ad20f8c28bc416d8382639717462a7)

Comment: Thanks one for question, is ' (expression)? ' the syntax for ignore? I understand what you did but my question in this comment is, is this how I am supposed to ignore certain patterns

Comment: You should probably become familiar with the regular expression syntax before trying to use it. [`?` Matches zero or one occurrence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix001.htm#i690819).

Comment: Thanks but the best way i know how to do it, is by  using non-capturing groups and i thought i had the syntax wrong, but it seems the syntax is not supported in oracle in the first place as i updated my question